# How to rename custom taxonomy URL with extra words

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, htaccess

There are 2000 Custom Taxonomies, called **tax_city** in my website
https://www.example.com/tax_city/london

and I want to change URL to something like this:

https://www.example.com/services/home-care/london

so, when someone visiting this URL, actually see taxonomy archive page. but with nicer URL.

I know this is possible somehow with htaccess but no idea start from which point.

any guide?

Comment: "I know this is possible somehow with htaccess" - not with `.htaccess` (at least, not with WordPress).

Answer (score 3):

You'd be better off adding or modifying the `rewrite` variable that's being passed to your [`register_taxonomy()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/) call for the custom taxonomy. You can modify the rewrites to suit your purpose.

For example:

```
$taxonomy_args = array(
    // All the variables and their values...
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'services/home-care',
    ),
    // ...more variables and values...
);

register_taxonomy( 'tax_city', $object_types, $taxonomy_args );
```

Be sure to flush your site's permalinks after you make the change.

Comment: Thank you, this one worked for me, adding as answer so maybe can be helpful for someone

function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^services/(.*)/(.*)?', 'index.php?service_category=$matches[1]&tax_city=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules');

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me.

```
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^services/(.*)/(.*)?', 'index.php?service_category=$matches[1]&tax_city=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
```